# 9 images shrinking together in a 3x3 grid in HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I have 9 images in a 3x3 grid shape on my web page.  At the moment it looks fine when I am viewing on my widescreen laptop, but when I view it on a smaller device the images stack on top of each other because it is responsive.  I would like the images to shrink down together (and remain in their 3x3 grid) instead of stacking.  I don't even know where to start.
Thanks in advance!

Sorry there isn't much to the code.  My section is 940px wide and each image is 300px wide and tall.

```
<section id="picture">
<img src="1.jpg">
<img src="2.jpg">
<img src="3.jpg">
<img src="4.jpg">
<img src="5.jpg">
<img src="6.jpg">
<img src="7.jpg">
<img src="8.jpg">
<img src="8.jpg">
</section>
```

Comment: You will need to post your existing code for any of us to figure out how to correct the issue you are having. Make sure to include the relevant CSS and HTML. Thanks!

Comment: Start at the beginning: http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design Are your images percentage based? They should be. Google for things like "fluid grid" or "flexible grid" for some examples.

Comment: I see you've added your HTML, but how about your CSS? The CSS is going to be the driving factor here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is by using `display:inline-block`, `max-widths` and percentages

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/Ptqde/

```
section {
    max-width:300px;
}
img {
    max-width:80px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:30%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked great.  For some reason mine still breaks when it reaches mobile phone size, but it works for tablets which is most important.

Comment: This will work down to size 0 in theory. If it breaks it is due to another element within your html or CSS that is disrupting things. Glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

I've whipped up [a sample of how to implement this](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/wRPp3/).

The HTML code is a simple unordered list with 9 empty `li` elements inside a `ul`. The CSS is a percentage based set of rules within their fixed size parent:

```
li {
    width:33%;
    height:33%;
    top:33%;
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
}
li:nth-child(-n+3) {
    top:0;
}
li:nth-child(n+7) {
    top:66%;
}
li:nth-child(3n+2) {
    left:33%;
}
li:nth-child(3n+3) {
    left:66%;
}
```

In my example I used a fixed background with `background-size:cover` to put the images on there - it speaks for itself that you can put anything in the `li` elements since this approach ensures they always have the correct size.